# how to make drf-yasg generate schema to add accept content type application/json for all the requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I want to add to all the paths that generated automatically by drf-yasg accept content type application/json by default. something like:

```
 "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/schema"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
```

I found something in DRF settings (setting.py) for the response but not for the request. Any help?

Comment: `drf-yasg` looking for `parser_classes` class attribute to set the content type of the request. So, if you set [`DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_parser_classes) or `parser_classes` to `JSONParser`, that would be enough.

Comment: If the above comment doesnt help you, please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with  detailed description of the issue.

Comment: That didn't worked...